# Edge web browser has constant cursor

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I use Microsoft edge, and I was always able to navigate up and down a web page using the up and down arrow keys.

However recently there is a cursor constantly on my browser, and the arrow keys now move the cursor.

I have searched google for this and found nothing.

Any suggestions on how I can remove the cursor ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reset Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was I had turn on something called `Caret Browsing`,

It can be turned on/off simply by pressing F7